# Find all solutions of the expression, where the sum of n variables equal an integer m. Variables and m are non-negative integers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i = m,\ x_i>=0,\ m >=0,\ x_i\in W,\ m \in W $$
OR
$$ x_1 + x_2 + ...+x_n = m,\ x_1,x_2,..,x_n >= 0,\ m >= 0,\ x_i\in W,\ m \in W $$

I have the expression. I know how to find count of solutions, we can use the Combinations with Repetition: 
$$ C^m_{(n)} = \frac{(n+m-1)!}{m!(n-1)!} $$
But I don't really know how can I get all solutions. I have to create a program that prints all solutions, but I can't find the algorithm. May be math will help me. Sorry for english.

Comment: Actually the no. of solutions is $^{m-1}C_{n-1}$ and not $^{n+m-1}C_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to create a program but I can help you how to interpret it algebraically.

Now, the value of each variable is integer which lies between $[0, m]$. This is same as distribution of $m$ identical objects to $n$ persons. Here, the identical objects are $m$ $1$'s and persons are the $n$ different variables.

Consider $n$ brackets corresponding to $n$ persons. In each bracket, take an expression given by $(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^m)$. Here, the various powers of $x$ viz: $0,1, 2,\dots,m$ correspond to the number of items each person can have in the distribution.

Since the total number of items is $m$. So, the required number of ways is the coefficient of $x^m$ in the product $$\underbrace{(x^0+x^1 +x^2+...+x^m)(x^0+x^1+x^2+...+x^m)\dots(x^0+x^1+x^2+...+x^m)}_{n-brackets}$$

Thus the required no. of ways are
$\begin{align}
\text{Coeff. of}\;x^m\;\text{in}\;(x^0+x^1+x^2+...+x^m)^n &=\text{Coeff. of}\;x^m\;\text{in}\;\left(\frac{1-x^{m+1}}{1-x}\right)^n\\
&=\text{Coeff. of}\;x^m\;\text{in}\;(1-x^{m+1})^n(1-x)^{-n}\\
&=\text{Coeff. of}\;x^m\;\text{in}\;(1-x)^{-n}\\
&={n+m-1\choose n-1}
\end{align}$

Comment: Pardon me. I had a mistake in my problem statement, and I edited it. Your answer will not change?

Comment: Yes, it will change i.e what you mentioned in your questions is correct. I'm editing my solution. I've also made one edit more that $x\in W$ and not $N$, because $0$ doesn't come in $N$.

Comment: Thank you. I edited it. May be this is silly questions, but can you explain what is $ Coeff.\ of x^m\ in\ expression $, and I don't understand you actions of transformations after the string $ =\text{Coeff. of}\;x^m\;\text{in}\;(x^0+x^1+x^2+...+x^m)^n\\ $. Could you advise some resources where can I learn it?

Comment: The transformation after the string is that I've wrote it as sum of GP.

Comment: Look, the $n$ bracket corresponds to $n$ persons and the powers of $x$ in each bracket corresponds to the number of objects the person can get in the distribution. Now, multiply the terms of each bracket with all terms in other brackets such that the power of $x$ by multiplying becomes $m$ because that's what max. no. of objects. We've to find all such multiplication combinations of $x$'s which can make the power of $x$ as $m$ i.e the coeff. of $x^m$ in the expansion.

Comment: I understand but not all. What is $ x $ in your answer? And how did you get the final part $ ={n+m-1\choose n-1} $ from the previous string, did you use binomial expansion?

Comment: There is no significance of $x$ but the powers of $x$ in each bracket which corresponds to the number of objects received by each person. And, yes, I used the binomial expansion for the final part.

Comment: Could you explain last steps, how we used the binomial expansion to get answer? I tried do it myself but I can't. Using the binomial expansion we work with expressions like $ (a+b)^m $, but here we have $ (1-x)^{-n} $, i.e. $ m = -n $, and it confused me.

Comment: I got it, thank you! We also can use maclaurin series to get a series expansion of $ (1-x)^{-n} $, and after take the coefficient of $ x^m $ in the expansion! But in the case $ x $ should be in $ (-1;1) $, but you said that there is no significance of x.

Comment: My vote are recorded, but it does not the publicly displayed, because I have only 13 reputation.